# Android Wear App shows a notification after uninstallation

Tags: android-wear

I installed Android Wear app for connecting with wearable emulator. After finished my job I uninstalled it. But the problem is, A notification is shown sometimes like "Android Wear connecting...". Can anyone tell me how can I get rid of it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved it. The notification which is showing after uninstall, I long pressed on that notification & go to its app info. It redirect me to google play service. I removed the cache & data. Now the notification does not appear.

Comment: On Android Lollipop you have to open the Play Services app through Settings - Apps - Google Play Services and then clear out all the data. Nevertheless, this pointed me in the right direction, so have a +1 for both the question and the answer.

Answer (score 1):

reinstall the android wear, after that press the three dot on the right upper part. then disconnect emulator, and press forget emulator. the notification gone forever!